# createComponent Salesforce lightning error

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am creating lightning component dynamically. On callback, I am facing a strange error which should not come.

```
 $A.createComponent(
            "c:TestComponent",
            {
                parameter1 : "hey"
            },
            function(newComponent, status){
                    var con = component.find('container');
                    if (component.isValid() && con.isValid() && status === 'SUCCESS') {
                        var body = con.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newComponent);
                        con.set("v.body", body);
                    }                
            });
```

and .cmp file I have

```
<div aura:id="container" class="slds-align-top"> 
</div>
```

and I am getting error in if condition.

```
con.isValid is not a function
```

Since container itself is not valid, I am not able to read the body of container where I want to include newly created component? 
What is wrong?

Comment: Can u make a debug on con? So do u get any results?
Have u also inspect the html code if this id is set correct?

Can you please provide the whole function?

Answer (score 0):

I Have just change the code please check on your end

```
$A.createComponent(
            "c:TestComponent",
            {
                parameter1 : "hey"
            },
            function(newComponent, status){

                    if (component.isValid()  && status === 'SUCCESS') {
var con = component.find('container');
                        var body = con.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newComponent);
                        con.set("v.body", body);
                    }                
            });
```

thanks
Dillip